# Monkey-patching console.log in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, monkeypatching

I am trying to apply [monkeypatching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply#Using_apply_in_.22monkey-patching.22) to [console.log](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.log) in [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/):

```
function doTheMonkey( ){
  console._log = console.log; //Typo, was console.log()

  console.log = function log( ){
      console._log.apply( this , arguments );    
      return arguments;
  }
}
```

PhantomJS will complain about **TypeError: Type error** for 
`console._log.apply( this , arguments );`

In order to drill down to the easiest example that fails, I can provide this:

```
function logAndReturn( ){
  console.log.apply( this , arguments );
  return arguments;
}
```

Similarly, it will fail with **TypeError: Type error** for 
`console._log.apply( this , arguments );`

This should just work, I have no idea what the root cause is..

Comment: Try to apply `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)`. Bus as far as I know in normal browsers, you cant use `apply` or `call` on `console.log`..

Comment: It should be `console` as context instead of `this`. Also second arg of `apply` is array. `console.log.apply(this, [10]);` works fine. Since `arguments` is array also, try to change context from `this` to `console`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in another answer, you should do

```
console._log = console.log
```

Then when you apply the `arguments` to `console._log`, you need to do

```
console._log.apply(console, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
```

The `arguments` value is not an array. With `slice` you create one.

Comment: Never noticed that `arguments` just have index access but is not an array.

Comment: Yeah.. `typeof arguments` returns 'object'. This can cause weird and hard to track bugs..

Answer (score 1):

You're calling console.log in the first line instead of taking a reference to the function, i.e.

```
console._log = console.log();
```

should be

```
console._log = console.log;
```